# I would like help Identifying this insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology

We found this in our house after coming in from outside but we are unsure if it came in on one of us (riding our coat) or was in our house before. We live in Massachusetts if that helps. We would like to know if anyone can ID these poor quality images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include an approximate size and any other contextual info you can think of. Additional better photos are also always useful for future visitors to comapre to. Thanks.